# Que signifie « gagner dans la durée » ?

Tags: sens, expressions

J'ai lu dans un texte ce passage :

> S’enraciner veut d’abord dire « se propager sur l’étendue au sein d’un
>   développement transversal et non l’étendue en profondeur au sens de
>   gagner dans la durée ».

Que signifie « gagner dans la durée » ?

Answer (score 3):

"gagner dans la durée" peut signifier **Sur le long terme**

> Situé dans la **perspective d’une échéance relativement éloignée.**

Exemples:

- Ces objectifs sont déterminés par un plan à long terme, pour
  l'atteinte duquel on ménagera au maximum ses forces tout en cherchant
  les prises les plus variées qu'offre la situation du moment. —
  (François Sellier, Stratégie de la lutte sociale, Les Éditions
  ouvrières, 1961, p.308)
- Il existe donc une relation à long terme et, par conséquent, il
  existe aussi une fonction de production. — (Marcelo Abreu, Dorte
  Verner, Croissance à long terme au Brésil, 1930-94, 1997)
- Le gouvernement de l’État a estimé qu'elle devait exécuter un plan de
  redressement à long terme. Ce plan devrait être établi par un
  échelon gouvernemental inférieur, mais le gouvernement de l’État a
  fixé un certain nombre de directives. — (Redressement des
  collectivités locales et régionales en difficulté financière, Conseil
  de l'Europe : Comité directeur sur la démocratie locale et régionale,
  2002, p. 19)

Source [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_long_terme)